# Getting a Gmail email as a string - also how do I obtain an image from the email

Tags: python, email, gmail, email-attachments, imaplib

I have retrieved the body of an email in Gmail using the following code. I now want to search it and pick out certain parts of the body text using something similar to the find command you use on strings. E.G.

```
DVRName = email_message[email_message.find("ALARM NAME(NUM):" +1:email_message.find("Report")-1]
```

When I try this it produces an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I assume this is because either I am using find incorrectly or the email data is not a string?

This code produces the email along with a lot of garbled code.

```
import imaplib
import datetime
from datetime import timezone
from email.parser import HeaderParser
timezone = ('gmt')

mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('f*****m', 'f******3')
mail.list()
# Out: list of "folders" aka labels in gmail.
mail.select("inbox") # connect to inbox.
result, data = mail.search(None, "All")

ids = data[0] # data is a list.
id_list = ids.split() # ids is a space separated string
latest_email_id = id_list[-1] # get the latest

# fetch the email body (RFC822) for the given ID
result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, ("(UID BODY[TEXT])"))

raw_email = data[0][1] # here's the body, which is raw text of the whole email
# including headers and alternate payloads
raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)

print (email_message)
```

One more thing can I retrieve the Subject, date etc separately?

Comment: So ... you're turning `raw_email_string` into a `message` type object, and *then* trying to use string methods on it? What happens if you use your string methods on `raw_email_string`?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean I remove the raw_email.decode command and it will be a string? (The decode does what exactly?

Comment: Thanks in advance! Will give it a try

Comment: Removed the decode command and it seems that data is a list. I get the following error:         'DVRName = data[data.find("ALARM NAME(NUM):")+1:data.find("Report")-1]
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find'        Is this correct and how do I either convert it to a string or serach the list?

Comment: I was more talking about the `email_message = email.message_from_string(raw_email_string)` line. If you have a list, the first thing to do is to inspect the elements of the list, and decide whether there exists an i such that you're confident that what you want is in the ith element of the list.

Comment: I have now realised the received data was a list and have printed the list to see whats in it. I converted it to a string and can now do my search.